# div vs image efficiency

Tags: image, html

What is a better solution in terms of size (page loading speed etc.):

I need to have many (up to a couple hundred) small, colored boxes (about 30x30 pixels or so) shown on a single website.  Should I

- Make each box a div with a colored background?
- Make each box an image loaded onto the page?

There are only a few (less than 6 colors) and these are being displayed in a table.

Thanks

Comment: backgorund color should be much more efficient than using big amount of images. But you can try to use CSS sprites for this purpose. You can read about that here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites. Anyway you can run some test. You can measure with JavaScript time of full load of the page. So test it :)

Comment: even if I am loading the same image many times?

Comment: Even if CSS Sprites are more efficient than normal background-images, it will be slower than background-color for sure, it still need to download a file and display it, background-color "is already on client computer", so there is only 1 CSS file to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colored background would be way better for many reasons:

1. the html tag will be smaller

   `<div class='xyz'></div>` compared to `<img src='images/yourfile.jpg'>`
2. background-color has no limit (well 17millions colors) while creating image will be long if you ever need more

**Edit:**
After reading back, if you are to put Colored Div into a table, would not it be easier to just put `<td class='redCell'></td>`?

Comment: response to your edit: I could do that, but I dont want the box to take up the entire cell